# can i use subquery instead of case

Tags: sql, subquery

```sql
DROP TABLE IF exists SAS;


CREATE TABLE sas (
    CUSTOMER_ID INT(3) NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NO INT(3) NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR(11),
    TRAN_AMOUNT INT(11),
    TRAN_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);


select * FROM SAS;



INSERT INTO SAS VALUES 
( 100 ,233 ,'SAVINGS' , 75000 , '2020-10-10'),
( 100 , 233 , 'SAVINGS' , 50000, '2020-8-23'),
( 100 , 234 , 'CURRENT' , 30000, '2020-11-1'),
(200, 239 , 'CURRENT' , 5000 , '2020-10-10'),
(200,238 , 'SAVINGS' , 7000 , '2020-11-10'),
(300,221 , 'SAVINGS' , 3000 , '2020-11-10'),
(300,223 , 'SAVINGS' , 45000 , '2020-11-10') ,
(300 , 224 , 'CURRENT' , 20000 , '2020-11-18'),
(300 , 224, 'CURRENT' , 35000 , '2020-11-18');

select * FROM SAS;


SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NO) AS NUM_ACCOUNTS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE account_type WHEN 'SAVINGS' THEN ACCOUNT_NO END) AS NUM_SAVINGS_ACCOUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT TRAN_DATE) AS NUM_DATE_TRANSACTED,
    SUM(TRAN_AMOUNT) AS TOT_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE account_type WHEN 'current' THEN TRAN_AMOUNT  END) AS tol_curr_amt
FROM
    sas
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: Using a subquery in place of a `CASE` statement *may* lead to inefficiencies.

Comment: You can, but why are you looking to do that? The query you've got looks perfectly reasonable

Comment: you can... but you should not use subquery unless you need to do so.  your query looks perfect given that the result what you want